# how to show a gif image as watch face wear OS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I have recently moved away from apple towards the android side of things, and I just bought a wear OS smartwatch looking into creating my own custom watch face.

I have been messing around with the example watch face project in android studio and that's all good and working, but I'm wondering if anybody has any suggestions on how to display a gif image as the background?

This is the line of code that sets an image as the background, but obviously it doesn't play gif images:

`mBackgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't you just convert the picture on your main computer once and for all, and use that line of code? Or do you need other functions like for animated gif files?

Comment: I'm looking to actually use the gif function, so it plays the animation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Movie to decode a gif file, then draw into your `WatchFaceService.Engine`'s `SurfaceHolder`'s `Canvas`

```
final Movie movie = Movie.decodeFile("your file path");
movie.setTie("gif's time offset");
movie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
```